# What are the type of drivers for Communication with Java?

Tags: mysql, java

I am developing one application using core java and Mysql Database.
As i read in Most of the site, they suggest that use type 4 driver for communication using JDBC.

In JDBC Connection i have use `mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar` from `Connector J 5.1.20.0` folder of Mysql 5.6.

My questions are.

1) `mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar` this one is which type of Driver.?

2) I want to use only for development purpose not to deploy so which one more suitable for me?

3) from where i'll get that drivers for development?

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect the Java application with the database you need the connector. You need to the mysql-connector.jar to connect the application with mysql database. It need to add both for standalone as well as for web application. 
You can download the .jar file from here.
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html